# Kubernetes logs format in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I have Kubernetes system in AWS (kops v1.4.4) and used the following instrustions to install fluent, elasticsearch and kibana: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch
I am able to see my pods logs in kibana but all kubernetes related metadata such as pod name , docker container id etc.. , locate under the same field (called tag) 
Is there any other modification I need to do in order to properly integrate Kubernetes with elasticsearch and Kibana?
Thank you

Comment: As far I can gather there is a field called tag which is being stored in elasticsearch which contains all information, but you want to break the information into more sub-fields. If thats the case you should refer to Logstash and create grok patterns to parse information from tag field and break it into multiple fields.

Comment: The new implementation using fluentd rather than logstash
Thanks
Jacky